# Which package is the Intel Smart Sound Technology device part of?

Tags: windows-10, audio, drivers

My client is having increasing problems with the above device stopping with STATUS_DEVICE_POWER_FAILURE. One three failed systems, you can disable and re-enable the device and it comes back. However, on one system today this didn't work to basically the machine is foobar'd as audio is down.

There is a thread on HP support forum about it so we're not alone but I'm trying to diagnose the fault and look at the driver to check we have the latest version.

However, this particular device isn't listed under audio section on the HP website - there's a Conexant device alone listed for the HP ProBook 430 G4. Neither can I find much on the Intel site. Is it part of the Intel chipset and therefore is the driver in the chipset driver package?

Comment: [analyze the dmp with windbg to see which driver](https://channel9.msdn.com/Shows/Defrag-Tools/Defrag-Tools-15-WinDbg-Bugchecks) is causing the issue

Comment: it's not bluescreening - the SST device simply stops. can I still debug this with windbg?

Comment: Later.. there was an update for the Intel video driver from HP which coaxed the failed SST device back into life. I'm guessing that the SST driver is part of the video driver package from Intel - kind of makes sense

Comment: no. this is a different issue. I misread that you got [DRIVER_POWER_STATE_FAILURE](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/windows-hardware/drivers/debugger/bug-check-0x9f--driver-power-state-failure). try to install the [driver from the HP site](https://support.hp.com/us-en/drivers/selfservice/hp-probook-430-g4-notebook-pc/10477243)